# Filtering a list of integer in range, to exclude the subsets in python

Tags: python, range, subset

I'm trying to find a faster way to filter my list of ranges, so that any range that can be covered completely by a larger range will be excluded. For example,

```
#all ranges have width >1, which means no such case like xx=[1,1] in my list
#each range itself is sorted. E.g. no such case like [1,3,2]. It is already like [1,2,3]
#each range only contains continuous integers. E.g. no such case like [3,5,7], it will only be like [3,4,5,6,7]. In fact, you could simply consider the first and last integer of the range to know the whole range.
aa=[1,2,3]
bb=[2,3,4]
cc=[1,2]
dd=[0,1,2]

RangeList=[aa,bb,cc,dd]

#FinalList=[aa,bb,dd]
```

cc can be covered by aa or dd (I consider it as a subset), so I'd like to exclude it. I definitely could write a loop for n^2 comparisons, but I would appreciate a faster method, since I have a lot of these ranges.

Comment: For arbitrary aa, bb, cc etc. I don't think you'll get any faster than n^2, since you have to more or less check each list in `RangeList` to see if any lists cover it. You could save some time by doing it the other way round - iterating through and discarding all lists that are sublists of each item. If there is some pattern in the sublists, you might be able to exploit that.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include any code you've written already?

Comment: What about if one list could be covered by two other lists, e.g. `aa=[1,2,3]; bb=[2,3,4]; cc=[1,4]`? Should you exclude `cc` because it can be covered by `aa` and `bb` when combined?

Comment: What about `aa=[1,2,3]; bb=[1,1]`? Should we exclude `bb`?

Comment: you should sort based on first and last elements of each list O(n log n) ..... next ....  filter sort list `RangeList` is O(n) ..... then O(n log n)+O(n) < O(n^2) ..... am I wrong?

Comment: Thanks @sweeneyrod, yes there is some minor pattern in my list, but I really don't think it matters at this point. I don't have a mature code ready at this point, but I'm going to work on it based on the commands you guys have kindly given. I think it will be very helpful to delete the ones that's already known being covered. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @JakeGriffin. I would like to still keep cc in your example. My list was eventually from a index of repeats on human genome, so simple overlapping is still considered to be different - at least for what is needed for my project :)

Comment: Good question @EllaShar. You don't need to worry about that, the width of my ranges are all >1. Thank you.

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. I think that's a great way to start! and I think the running time is correct --- took algorithm long time ago though:p Thank you!

Comment: So all your lists are already sorted? If not, could there be a list like [1, 3, 1] or does it have width=1? So each list has no two identical items?

Comment: @EllaShar that's correct. each range itself is sorted. no identical items. Thank you:)

Comment: Another question: What should the output be for `ranges=[[1,3,5], [2,4]]`?

Comment: Oh wow, I never thought of all these cases, but all my ranges are with continuous integers. so your example doesn't happen in my case. Sorry about the confusion - I'm going to edit my post to make it clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve this by sorting first:

```
import operator
ranges=[[0,1,2,3,4], [1,2], [0,1], [2,3,4], [3,4,5], [3,4,5,6], [4,5], [6,7], [5,6]]
sorted_ranges = sorted(ranges,key=operator.itemgetter(-1),reverse=True)
sorted_ranges = sorted(sorted_ranges,key=operator.itemgetter(0))

filtered = []
i,j = 0,0    

while i < len(sorted_ranges):
    filtered.append(sorted_ranges[i])
    j = i+1
    while j < len(sorted_ranges) and sorted_ranges[i][-1] >= sorted_ranges[j][-1]:
        print "Remove " , sorted_ranges.pop(j) , "dominated by",sorted_ranges[i]
    i+=1

print "RESULT",filtered
```

You will need to sort on the first element in ascending order and descending order for the last element.
I used two explicit calls of sorted but you could define your cmp function to do this in one pass:

```
sorted_ranges = sorted(ranges,cmp=lambda x,y: (x[0]-y[0]) if ((x[0]-y[0]) != 0 ) else (y[-1]-x[-1]))
```

In this way dominating ranges will appear first.
Notice that the nested while loop after sorting has complexity O(n) since each element is examined only once and either removed or added to the final set.
Complexity of the whole algorithm is O(nlogn)

Comment: fails to `ranges=[[0,1,2,3,4], [1,2], [0,1], [2,3,4], [3,4,5], [3,4,5,6], [4,5], [6,7], [5,6]]`

Comment: default lexicographic ordering does not work, I will fix my solution

Comment: For `ranges=[[3,2,2,1], [2,2]]` this returns `[[2, 2]]` which is wrong.

Comment: Very nice method. Thank you very much @igon. I appreciate it!

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't work... `ranges=[[3, 2, 4], [2, 4]]`. The logic in this algoritms is not even close to cover all the cases.

Comment: @EllaShar [3,2,4] should not be a valid input. Anyway it is easy to modify the code to consider not sorted sequences. Just change the cmp function to use max() and min() instead of the elements in position 0 and -1.

Comment: A sorted case where this doesn't work: [[1,3, 5, 7], [3, 6]] - the [3, 6] will be excluded although it's not a subset of [1, 3, 5, 7]

Comment: This is yet another problem, the original question has only python ranges. To solve in the case of sets taken from the power set the approach I mention is still valid. You need to use topological sort though since inclusion in P(set) is only a partial order.

Comment: Using a topological order could be a good approach. But I think it's too slow since you need to construct the graph. Also, you don't really need a topological order, you just need to eliminate the lists that appear in the left side of the `<` partial order. Could you elaborate on this approach? I couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sets` , `issubset()`, `filter()`:

```
ranges = [[0,1,2,3,4], [1,2], [0,1], [2,3,4], [3,4,5], [3,4,5,6], [4,5], [6,7], [5,6]]

# Use 'frozenset' as it is hashable to put in a big 'set'
sets = set([frozenset(a) for a in ranges])

def f(x): 
    for y in sets: 
        if x == y:
            continue
        if x.issubset(y):
            return False
    return True

result = [list(a) for a in filter(f, sets)]
print 'Result=', result
```

The `f` function filters out any set found in the input.

```
Result= [[3, 4, 5, 6], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [6, 7]]
```

Haven't run performance tests though.

Comment: nice use of frozenset but this is O(n^2)

Comment: Thanks. Would it help to first sort the input by length, and traversing it in reverse in the loop? I need to put this in another answer...

Comment: Thank you very much for your code @GCord. I appreciate it, but unfortunately I need a faster method.

Comment: Of course @Helene! This solution is O(n^2) which you mentioned wouldn't fit the bill... I should also have paid more attention to the fact you mentioned "ranges", and then some optimizations became possible.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was:

```
compressed = dict()
for lst in sorted(RangeList,reverse=True, key= lambda x: (x[0],x[1])):
    key = lst[0]
    if key not in compressed:
        compressed[key] = lst
print compressed.values()
```

But as igon pointed out, that misses interior subsets.  I think the following will fix that:

```
RangeList = sorted(RangeList,reverse=True, key= lambda x: (-x[0],x[-1]))
lst = RangeList[0]
oldstart = lst[0]
oldend = lst[-1]
compressed = {oldstart: lst}
for lst in RangeList[1:]:
    start = lst[0]
    end = lst[-1]
    if (start not in compressed and oldend < end):
        compressed[start] = lst
        oldstart, oldend = start, end

print compressed.values()
```

Comment: does it work for: `RangeList = [[0,1,2,3,4], [1,2], [0,1], [2,3,4], [3,4,5], [3,4,5,6], [4,5], [6,7], [5,6]]` ?

Comment: It doesn't. It returns `[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5], [5, 6], [6, 7]]`

Answer (score 0):

This uses `set` and `issubset`, but first sorts the lists by size, and the `filter` function traverses the input again in reverse order, trying to optimize the search. This could improve the O() order.

```
ranges = [[0,1,2,3,4], [1,2], [0,1], [2,3,4], [3,4,5], [3,4,5,6], [4,5], [6,7], [5,6]]

sets = [set(a) for a in ranges]
sets.sort(key=len)
reverse_sets = sets[:]
reverse_sets.reverse()

def f(x): 
    for y in reverse_sets:
        if x == y:
            continue
        if x.issubset(y):
            return False
    return True

print 'Result=', [list(a) for a in filter(f, sets)]
```

Result:

```
Result= [[6, 7], [3, 4, 5, 6], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: It doesn't improve the `O()` order, since `O` means worst case and in the worst case (If there are no lists to exclude - no subsets) this is still `O(n^2)`